# Why isnt the Kendo Grid inline editable?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid in html as follows:

```
<div 
     kendo-grid="grid"
     k-options="gridOptions"
     k-data-source="gridData"
     k-selectable="true"
     k-columns="gridColumns"
     k-editable="editableOptions">
</div>
```

The Angular back end is:

```
    $scope.gridData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: $scope.users, <-- the data binds correctly in the grid
        editable: {
            createAt: "bottom"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "string", visible: true },
                    Name: { type: "string", editable: true }
                }
            }
        },
        sort: [
            { field: "Name", dir: "asc" }
        ],
        pageSize: 15,
        editable: true
    });

    $scope.gridOptions = {

    };

    $scope.gridColumns = [
        { field: 'Name', title: 'First Name', width: 60 },
        { field: 'Id', title: ' ',  width: 120 },
        {
            command: ["destroy"],
            title: " ",
            width: "175px",
            editable: "inline"
        }

    ];
    $scope.editableOptions = "inline";
```

So the User Data Load correctly with 5 rows, but there should be an extra row at the bottom for adding a new  user via the line

```
editable: {
    createAt: "bottom"
},
```

but this is not being created when the grid loads.

Also, they should be able to delete via the following command

```
{
    command: ["destroy"],
    title: " ",
    width: "175px",
    editable: "inline"
}
```

but this is also not being displayed.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**make the row editable when clicking on the edit button:**

Define `editable` once, like this:

```
editable: {
    mode: "inline" , 
    createAt: "bottom"
},
```

Your `command`:

```
{
  command: ["edit","destroy"]
}
```

and also add `toolbar` for create:

```
toolbar: ["create"]
```

Here is a sample : [Sample Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UCEseRAp)

---

**make it editable once click in the cell:**

editable:

```
editable: {
    createAt: "bottom"
},
```

command:

```
{
  command: ["destroy"]
}
```

toolbar:

```
toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
```

and also in your `dataSource` set `batch: true`

Here is a sample: [Sample Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OZOXEmiY)

Comment: This doesnt make the row editable unless they click on the edit button. How to make it editable once that click in the cell ?

Comment: The sample project adds a new row via a button click . I was wanting to add a new row after the user tabs out of the last editable cell in the grid. And if the cell is not populated and they tab , no new row is created .